# Convert geojson to geopandas dataframe

Tags: dataframe, openstreetmap, geojson, geopandas

I am using OpenRouteService API and I am trying to convert the GeoJSON result of the GET Directions service to a GeoPandas dataframe and, in the end, store it as a spatial PostGIS table. My code so far is:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import sqlalchemy as sa
import openrouteservice

def getroute(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    coords = ((lon1, lat1), (lon2, lat2))
    params_route = {'profile': 'foot-walking','coordinates' : coords,
               'format_out': 'geojson',
               'geometry': 'true','geometry_simplify':'true',
               'geometry_format': 'geojson',
               'instructions': 'false',
               }
    geometry = client.directions(**params_route)['features']
    print geometry
    return geometry

# Creating SQLAlchemy's engine to use
client = openrouteservice.Client(key='myapikey')
lon1=8.34234
lat1=48.23424
lon2=8.34423
lat2=48.26424
myroutes = getroute(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2)
print myroutes
print type(myroutes)
myroutes = gpd.GeoDataFrame(myroutes)
print myroutes
engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@host/database', encoding = 'utf-8')
with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    # Note use of regular Pandas `to_sql()` method.
    myroutes['geometry'].to_sql('contents', con=conn, schema='schema', if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

However, I can't seem to overpass the geojson structure and store it. Can anyone help me? The resulting error is

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'dict' [SQL: 'INSERT INTO paa.contents (geometry) VALUES (%(geometry)s)'] [parameters: {'geometry': {u'type': u'LineString', u'coordinates': [[8.344268, 48.233826], [8.344147, 48.233507], [8.344098, 48.233435], [8.343945, 48.233136], [8.343853, 48.233047], [8.34332, 48.232736], [8.343098, 48.232473], [8.342861, 48.232307], [8.342711, 48.23224], [8.342328, 48.232159], [8.342045, 48.23209], [8.341843, 48.232035], [8.341711, 48.231946], [8.341092, 48.232163], [8.340386, 48.232388], [8.34028, 48.23245], [8.339983, 48.23274], [8.339451, 48.23315], [8.3393, 48.233316], [8.339219, 48.233457], [8.339185, 48.233646], [8.339372, 48.234329], [8.339367, 48.234539], [8.339262, 48.234685], [8.338886, 48.234971], [8.338431, 48.235181], [8.338327, 48.23528], [8.338234, 48.235495], [8.338176, 48.235798], [8.338105, 48.235955], [8.337919, 48.236102], [8.33725, 48.236483], [8.336922, 48.236771], [8.336726, 48.237039], [8.336421, 48.237391], [8.33621, 48.237641], [8.336115, 48.237759], [8.335913, 48.237947], [8.335782, 48.23804], [8.335572, 48.238146], [8.335367, 48.238292], [8.335175, 48.238458], [8.335038, 48.238638], [8.335097, 48.238674], [8.335049, 48.238932], [8.335044, 48.239155], [8.334709, 48.239726], [8.334583, 48.239904], [8.33455, 48.240095], [8.334344, 48.240506], [8.334089, 48.240776], [8.334175, 48.240817], [8.334326, 48.240799], [8.334562, 48.240779], [8.335146, 48.240961], [8.335056, 48.241105], [8.334592, 48.241447], [8.334338, 48.241616], [8.333982, 48.241818], [8.333449, 48.242185], [8.333166, 48.242623], [8.333047, 48.242774], [8.33289, 48.242884], [8.332437, 48.243097], [8.332313, 48.243212], [8.332203, 48.2434], [8.332093, 48.243811], [8.331966, 48.244102], [8.331775, 48.244413], [8.331649, 48.244575], [8.331717, 48.24471], [8.331836, 48.244822], [8.332961, 48.245226], [8.33325, 48.245292], [8.333439, 48.245365], [8.333781, 48.245519], [8.334241, 48.245794], [8.334417, 48.245979], [8.333901, 48.246311], [8.33362, 48.246637], [8.33304, 48.246836], [8.332729, 48.247071], [8.332437, 48.247353], [8.332278, 48.247583], [8.332271, 48.247685], [8.332345, 48.247923], [8.332441, 48.248093], [8.332291, 48.248137], [8.331258, 48.248526], [8.330556, 48.248909], [8.329865, 48.249228], [8.329128, 48.249545], [8.328832, 48.249737], [8.328606, 48.249949], [8.328412, 48.250198], [8.328342, 48.250322], [8.328084, 48.250757], [8.327975, 48.25103], [8.32782, 48.251499], [8.327715, 48.251941], [8.327707, 48.252051], [8.327735, 48.252168], [8.327871, 48.252433], [8.328022, 48.252827], [8.328051, 48.252982], [8.328067, 48.253367], [8.328094, 48.253482], [8.328188, 48.253678], [8.328516, 48.253748], [8.329388, 48.253956], [8.329619, 48.25405], [8.32993, 48.254114], [8.330179, 48.254184], [8.330565, 48.254448], [8.33078, 48.254627], [8.330909, 48.254812], [8.331049, 48.255072], [8.331165, 48.255189], [8.331417, 48.25535], [8.331592, 48.255536], [8.331745, 48.255884], [8.331778, 48.256163], [8.331733, 48.256781], [8.331604, 48.257332], [8.332141, 48.257903], [8.332452, 48.258317], [8.332688, 48.258781], [8.332668, 48.259148], [8.332765, 48.259448], [8.33286, 48.259582], [8.333589, 48.259789], [8.333881, 48.259898], [8.334074, 48.259932], [8.334615, 48.260141], [8.334832, 48.260261], [8.335546, 48.260712], [8.335655, 48.260829], [8.335753, 48.260994], [8.335783, 48.261319], [8.33623, 48.261624], [8.337095, 48.261891], [8.337525, 48.262004], [8.33783, 48.262411], [8.337898, 48.262441], [8.337994, 48.262433], [8.338356, 48.26232], [8.338735, 48.262012], [8.339091, 48.261771], [8.339439, 48.261581], [8.339604, 48.261778], [8.339748, 48.261829], [8.339754, 48.26183], [8.33996, 48.262052], [8.340984, 48.262661], [8.341287, 48.262828], [8.341604, 48.262945], [8.342296, 48.263073], [8.343026, 48.263176], [8.343188, 48.263176], [8.343387, 48.263132], [8.3438, 48.262989], [8.343999, 48.26297], [8.344228, 48.263014], [8.344626, 48.263142], [8.344987, 48.263166], [8.345244, 48.263242], [8.344865, 48.263233], [8.344067, 48.263207], [8.343897, 48.263233], [8.343478, 48.263529], [8.343433, 48.263552]]}}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it:

```
geometry = client.directions(**params_route)['routes'][0]
geometry = pd.DataFrame({k : pd.Series(v) for k, v in geometry.iteritems()})
geometry = geometry[:-2]
geometry['coordinates'] = geometry['geometry'].apply(Point)
geometry['myline'] = 1
geometry = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry, geometry='coordinates')
geometry = geometry.groupby('myline')['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x.tolist()))
geometry = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry, geometry='geometry')
myroute = LineString(geometry['geometry'].iloc[0]).wkb_hex
# Update table:
insert_query = """UPDATE schema.contents SET geom = ST_GeomFromWKB(%(geometry)s::geometry, 4326) WHERE id='1'"""
engine.execute(insert_query, geometry=myroute)
```